# Matrix Enumeration Lab

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix, permutation

Your job is to write a program called matrix_enum, which takes three command line arguments: W, E and either an 'x' or an 'h'. Your program will enumerate all of the matrices for W and E, in any order you want, and print them out in one of the following two formats:

- If the last argument is 'x', then you'll print the matrices out in the format below. You should print each matrix as W lines of W characters that are '.', 'X' or 'E'. After each matrix, you print a blank line.
- If the last argument is 'h', then you'll convert each line of each matrix into an integer, and print that integer in hexadecimal, with no leading 0's and no leading "0x". If element i in a row is 'X' or 'E', then you'll set the i-th bit of the number to 1. Otherwise, the i-th bit is zero. You'll print each integer on its own line, and print a blank line at the end of each matrix.

---

UNIX> matrix_enum 2 0 x

X.

.X

.X

X.

---

UNIX> matrix_enum 2 0 h

1

2

2

1

---

Here's my code so far but I don't know where to go from here

```
  5 class Matrix {
  6     public:
  7         int W;
  8         int E;
  9         int P;                      /* This is 'x' or 'h' */
 10         vector <int> Perm;          /* Permutation of 0 .. (W-1), for the 'X' elements. */
 11         vector <int> Non_X;         /* This is the row/col id of each of the non-X elements. */
 12         vector <int> E_ID;          /* This is the row/col id of the E elements */
 13         void Print();               /* Print the matrix defined by W, Perm and E_ID */
 14         void Permute(int index);    /* This is the recursive permuting method. */
 15         void Choose(int index);     /* This is the recursive n-choose-k method. */
 16 };
 17 
 18 void Matrix::Print() {
 19 
 20     for(int i = 0; i < Perm.size(); i++) {
 21 
 22 
 23     }
 24 }
 25
 26  void Matrix::Permute(int index) {
 27     //recursion to permute matrix
 28     string tmp;
 29 
 30     if(index == Perm.size()) {
 31         //Base case
 32         for (int i = 0; i < W; i++) {
 33             for(int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
 34                 //check if there is an 'x'
 35                 if(Perm.at(i) == j) {
 36                     continue;
 37                 }
 38 
 39                 Non_X.push_back(Perm.at(i));
 40                 Choose(0);
 41                 return;
 42             }
 43         }
 44     }
 45     //swap Perm[index] with Perm[i] and swap back
 46     for(int i = index; i < Perm.size(); i++) {
 47         //swap
 48         tmp = Perm[i];
 49         Perm[i] = Perm[index];
 50         Perm[index] = tmp;
 51 
 52         Permute(index+1);
 53 
 54         //backtrack
 55         tmp = Perm[i];
 56         Perm[i] = Perm[index];
 57         Perm[index] = tmp;
 58     }
 59 }
 60 
 61 void Matrix::Choose(int index) {
 62     //n choose k permutation
 63     //people = non x
 64     //eid = teams
 65     if (E - E_ID.size() == 0) {
 66         cout << E_ID[0];
 67         for (i = 1; i < E_ID.size(); i++) cout << " " << E_ID[i];
 68         cout << endl;
 69         return;
 70     }
 71 
 72     if ((E - E_ID.size()) > Non_X.size() - index) return;
 73 
 74     E_ID.push_back(Non_X[index]);
 75     Choose(index+1, (E - E_ID.size())-1);
 76     E_ID.pop_back();
 77 
 78     Choose(index+1, (E - E_ID.size()));
 79 
 80     // call Print();
 81 }
```

Comment: Next you need to create a [mre] that uses the class Matrix.  Be sure to include a) test input and b) the inputs corresponding output, and c) describe what is not working/

Comment: Also line numbers are more disruptive than helpful in this code example. If someone wants to copy, compile and play with the code, it's quite tedious to have to remove all those line numberings first.

Comment: Actually, line numbers are quite pretty to address individual lines in comments. To prevent compiling issues after copy/pasting the code, they could be formatted as C-style comments. (Notepad++ as well as VS2013 and newer provide a block-edit mode which would make this an easy job. Other editors/IDEs might provide something similar. Or just use `sed`...) ;-)